# How would you pass two arguments for threadpoolexecutor in python?

Tags: python

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from functools import partial

threads = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20)

def check_and_execute(name, key):
        response = s.get(f"www.google.com?search={name}", verify=False)
        data = response.get_json()["content"]
        if data["host_name"] == key:
                return data["host_name"]

def list_of_names(hub="abcdef"):
       response = s.get(f"www.abcd.com?search={hub}", verify=False)
       data = response.get_json()["content"]
       for x in range(len(data)):
              key = data["host_key"]
              name = data["name_of_host"]
```

Above is the sample code format that I have. I want to use ThreadPoolExecutor inside the list_of_names() to pass in name & key values to check_and_execute().

Should I make a list of keys & names and use map to do it? Or can I use partial and map combination to pass in the respective values to other function ?